# Faster than O(N²) solution to sum all integer divisions over an array

Tags: arrays, math, integer, integer-division

I was given this snippet of code as an assignment.

```c
int arr[n];
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
   sum += arr[i] / arr[j];
  }
}
```

Assumptions: n < 10⁶, all elements in arr are of type int and are smaller than 10⁶

My task is to return sum faster than O(n²) time. I've been thinking about this for the past few hours and I can't seem to find any way to speed it up (apart from O((n²+n)/2) which I would achieve by sorting the numbers and dividing only while the numerator is larger than the denominator).

Comment: Big-O notation isn't about speed, but about *complexity*.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

***please provide us more code deatails***

And by the way , in general you can sort in O(nlogn) (merge sort,insertion sort and more) and that will be must better then O((n²+n)/2) in runtime terms.